# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, iis, crystal-reports, log4net

I am getting this error since last 2 days in my Server where I had hosted application.

I had already tried most of the scenario mentioned here. but not getting anything.

Here is my stack trace -

> ```
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>         dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]  
> CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils..cctor() +0
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>         'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.]   
> CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.get_CurrentControl() +18   
> CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.GetEffectiveCulture() +8   
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CREngineRes.GetString(String name) +11   
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime() +143
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +131
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>         'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.]   
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +0
> AdminReports..ctor() +25
> ASP.reportviewer_aspx..ctor() +14
> __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_reportviewer_aspx_cdcab7d2.Create_ASP_reportviewer_aspx() +20 
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>         virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +109   
> System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType,
>         VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31 
> System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType,
>         String virtualPath, String path) +37   
> System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +334
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
> ```

Already configured my IIS to allow applications to run on 32bit.

Comment: It looks like Crystal Reports has a dependency on version 1.2.10.0 of log4net. Is 1.2.10.0 the version you are using in your application? Or are you using a newer/older version?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue, and what fixed it for me was going to the program properties (under Project -> "Program Name" Properties) and then under the publish area, find the Application Files, and find the Log4net.dll.

This was set to "Include(Auto)" for me, but that did not actually include it in the Program. when i set this to "Include" That fixed that issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the log4net.dll or have a different version than Version=1.2.10.0 in your bin directory. Make sure you package the right log4net.dll (version). Or if you have multiple versions in your project you can try to rebind the versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify your DLL version in your app.  If wrong version get the correct version using NuGet.
2. Verify DLL property "Copy Local" set to True
3. Under project properties, set the Platform Target to x86.

Answer (score 0):

For me the log4net file was there and version correct but the problem was missing runtime. Downloaded it here: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/